# Playwright loads blank page when navigating to bing search

Tags: python, playwright, playwright-python

I just wanted to try out playwright and I ran into an issue.
When I create a page directly from the browser and navigate between pages it works
but when I create a context and then try navigating,  only the first URL loads correctly
and it happens only with Bing search, google search loads correctly in both conditions
I thought there must be some error so I tried in GUI mode also

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

# This works
with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=False)
    page = browser.new_page()

    page.goto("https://bing.com")
    input("->")

    page.goto("https://bing.com/search?q=Google+search")
    input("->")


# But this does not
with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=False)
    browser_context = browser.new_context()
    page = browser_context.new_page()

    page.goto("https://bing.com")
    input("->")

    page.goto("https://bing.com/search?q=Google+search")
    input("->")
```

The Bing search should load normally like google search, but it doesn't.

Comment: What version of Playwright are you using? This works fine for me on Ubuntu 22.04 with Python Playwright 1.40 and Python 3.10.12.

Comment: Upgrade your playwright, your code works fine for me, Py 3.12

Comment: Thanks, but both python and playwright are already on the latest version.
Reinstalling playwright fixed this issue

Comment: If you want to use bing, why not load in msedge instead? You can do that with: `browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=False, channel="msedge")`, so you can search with bing.

Comment: @5rod Thanks for suggestion, but that issue got fixed by reinstalling playwright